# Use name of controllers to find table name in Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to extract a `ID` , `User_ID` value from one of the `Companies` and `Contract` tables, depending on the `ContorollerName` value.

```
select P.TitleProject, P.StartDateProject, P.EndDateProject,P.ControllerID,P.RecordID,P.IsAllocated,P.ProjectStatus_ID,
CN.ControllerName,CN.PersianName,
PU.ProjectID,PU.UserID,PU.RoleID,
    CASE
        WHEN CN.ControllerName = 'Company' THEN 
            Companies.Id,Companies.[User_Id]
        WHEN CN.ControllerName = 'Contract' THEN 
            Contracts.Id,Contracts.[User_Id]
        END
from Projects P
    left outer join Controllers CN ON P.ControllerID = CN.Id
    left outer join ProjectUsers PU ON P.Id = PU.ProjectID
where P.IsAllocated = 1
```

For example, if `ContorollerName` is 'Company' , the `select` command is as follows :

```
select P.TitleProject, P.StartDateProject, P.EndDateProject,P.ControllerID,P.RecordID,P.IsAllocated,P.ProjectStatus_ID,
CN.ControllerName,CN.PersianName,
PU.ProjectID,PU.UserID,PU.RoleID,
Companies.Id,Companies.[User_Id]
```

Comment: You did not finished your question, right? It looks as interrupted before actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track -- using `left join`.  But you need to add the tables to the `from` clause with the appropriate logic.

The logic for the join is quite unclear.  The query looks something like this:

```
select . . .,
       coalesce(c.id, co.id) as id,
       coalesce(c.user_id, co.user_id) as user_id
from Projects P left join
     Controllers CN 
     on P.ControllerID = CN.Id left join
     ProjectUsers PU
     on P.Id = PU.ProjectID left join
     companies c
     on c.? = ? and   -- no idea what the right join conditions are
        c.ControllerName = 'Company' left join
     contracts co
     on co.? = ? and  -- no idea what the right join conditions are
        co.ControllerName = 'Contract' 
where P.IsAllocated = 1
```